# Unable to capture a frame of a specific game in PIX for Windows, although in other game it works

Tags: pix

I'm trying to get the 3D models from a 2001 3D DirectX game with PIX for windows. It just doesn't work for some reason.I tried all options from PIX (A single frame capture of Direct3D,A replayable Direct3D call stream etc. I tested by trying on other more recent game and works.

What can I do to make it work?
Thank you.

Comment: I want this only to polish the models in Studio Max.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a game you're developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game from 2001 most likely use Direct3D 8 since 9 was released 2002.

Pix is a very deprecated tool used only for debugging your own applications written in Direct3D 9+.